# How to send json message from Kinesis to MSK and then to elastic search using kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have set up ready and the flow also is working.
I am sending my data from Kinesis stream to MSK using lambda function and the format of the message is below

```
{
        "data": {
                "RequestID":    517082653,
                "ContentTypeID":        9,
                "OrgID":        16145,
                "UserID":       4,
                "PromotionStartDateTime":       "2019-12-14T16:06:21Z",
                "PromotionEndDateTime": "2019-12-14T16:16:04Z",
                "SystemStartDatetime":  "2019-12-14T16:17:45.507000000Z"
        },
        "metadata":     {
                "timestamp":    "2019-12-29T10:37:31.502042Z",
                "record-type":  "data",
                "operation":    "insert",
                "partition-key-type":   "schema-table",
                "schema-name":  "dbo",
                "table-name":   "TRFSDIQueue"
        }
}
```

This json message i am sending into kafka topic like below

```
props.put("acks", "all");
            props.put("retries", 0);
            props.put("batch.size", 16384);
            props.put("linger.ms", 1);
            props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
            props.put("producer.type", "async");
            props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
            System.out.println("Inside loop successfully");
            try {
                producer.send(
                        new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array())));
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("------------Exception message=-------------" + e.toString());
            }

            finally {
                producer.flush();
                producer.close();
            }
```

When i start kafka connect for elastic search i get error like

```
DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error
```

Also i have modified quickstart-elasticsearch.properties and changed key value serializer as string .

When it was json it was throwing error .

I can see indices is getting created with kafka topic name in elastic search but no record .

So please help me with my few confusion .
1. Am i sending message correctly from producer kinesis stream ?
  i am using

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

or should i use json here .But there is no json as such .

2. Or do i have to use json serializer in `quickstart-elasticsearch.properties`?
3. If event is insert then it will insert record in elastci search what about delete and update ,Kafka-connect handle delete and update for us in elastic search ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should never sleep the producer. That's not how you verify message delivery. You should use `producer.send().get()` to make it a blocking call, and even add an OnCompleteListener to know which partition and offset was produced to... In any case, please show your connector config.

Comment: And can you please provide more of the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 30 day free trial, you can use the [Kinesis Source Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-kinesis/index.html), or you can learn how to write your own Source Connector and deploy it alongside the Elasticsearch sink rather than use a lambda at all...

---

Secondly, work backwards. Can you create a fake topic and send records of the same format **outside of lambda**? Do those end up in Kafka? How about Elasticsearch? And remove Kibana from the equation, too, if you're using it and it's not working

*Then* focus on the lambda integration

---

To answer your questions

1) You're sending JSON *as a string*. You don't need a separate serializer for JSON unless you are sending POJO classes that get mapped into JSON strings within the serializer interface.

You're sending JSON records, so you should be using JSONConverter, in Connect, yes. However, I don't think Elasticsearch mappings will be automatically created unless you [have a schema and payload](https://rmoff.net/2017/09/06/kafka-connect-jsondeserializer-with-schemas.enable-requires-schema-and-payload-fields/), so simple workaround to that is to create the ES index mapping ahead of time (however if you already know that, you therefore have designed a schema, so it ultimately is the responsibility of the producer code to send the right record).

If you define the mapping ahead of time, you should be able to simply use StringConverter in Connect

The only things I would change about your producer code is having retries higher than 0. And use try with resources rather than explicitly closing the producer

```
//... parse input 
try (Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props)) {
//... send record 
}
```

2) You can search the Github issues for the connector, but last I checked, it does full document updates and inserts, no partial updates or any deletes

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer.Just few clarification ,So basically i need to create schema and then use schema registry ? Also lambda is just for testing purpose .My real use case is to send data from Aurora to MSK and from MSK to Elastic search .For that again i need to have kafka-connect-jdbc which already i have seen in included .I am trying out there but have few clarification .So can i update my question or i think i should ask another one ? I think i should ask another one .But thank you so much for the learning i am getting on this forum and grateful to you specially answering very basic

Comment: You can use Avro GenericRecord instead by editing your producer code, sure, but **it is not required**. Do not confuse having a JSON Schema with needing to use Schema Registry. I personally would try to use Debezium from Aurora

Comment: I am sorry i did not get your point here .Ok let me put another question with all details .

Comment: You don't need Avro, but you can create kafka producers using it. However, then you must deploy a Schema Registry to store Avro schemas. Otherwise, you can embed Kafka Connect schema definitions, only with JSON converter. If you have no schemas at all, you must create an elasticsearch mapping manually to correctly index your data... Or use logstash kafka consumer which knows how to parse JSON into elasticsearch better without kafka connect schemas